# Upstart job (haproxy)

Tags: haproxy, upstart

I am starting HA proxy using the following command: 
**sudo etc/init.d/haproxy start**
and I stop HA proxy using:
**sudo etc/init.d/haproxy stop**
How can I write a basic upstart script for sudo etc/init.d/something start or stop ?

Answer (score 4):

The following script will work. Put it in "/etc/init/haproxy.conf", then you can start the haproxy service with "service haproxy start". Be sure to check the location of the configuration file

```
# HAProxy 

description     "HAProxy"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
respawn limit 2 5

env CONF=/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

pre-start script
    [ -r $CONF ]
end script

exec /usr/local/sbin/haproxy -db -f $CONF
```